# Overwrite file names when uploading catalog images to Magento

Tags: magento

When you upload a product image to Magento that has the same name as an existing image, normal behavior for Magento is to append a "_1" to the end of the new file name. So if I have an image named "myFile.png" and upload a second image to the same product with that same name, Magento will rename it to "myFile_1.png".  I would like to eliminate this renaming and have files of the same name replace an existing file.

I think I found the relevant controller at: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    try {
        $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
        $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image',
            Mage::helper('catalog/image'), 'validateUploadFile');
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $result = $uploader->save(
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseTmpMediaPath()
        );

        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after', array(
            'result' => $result,
            'action' => $this
        ));

        /**
         * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
         */
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['path']);

        $result['url'] = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getTmpMediaUrl($result['file']);
        $result['file'] = $result['file'] . '.tmp';
        $result['cookie'] = array(
            'name'     => session_name(),
            'value'    => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path'     => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain'   => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain()
        );

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'errorcode' => $e->getCode());
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

I have tried setAllowedRenameFiles() to false. I have also tried commenting it out. But neither of these seems to give the desired results.

Any thoughts on how I can enable Magento to overwrite existing files of the same name?

Comment: Same issue there...